# Calling two javascript files at once using HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have one html file and two .js files. I am putting multiple script tags in one html file because I am using backbone js.

```
<html>
   <body>
     <script type="text/x-template" id="my-template">
        some html contents
        <script src="/javascripts/validation.js"></script>
        <script src="/javascripts/other.js"></script>
      </script>
      <script type="text/x-template" id="myfile-template">
        some html contents
      </script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

My problem is that I am unable to call 2 js files from my-template script. In the above code, only "validation.js" is called and if I put "other.js" first then only "other.js" is called.

```
<script src="/javascripts/other.js"></script>
 <script src="/javascripts/validation.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why can't you put the two scripts where you put the jQuery one?

Answer (score 1):

You can't put  tags inside other  tags.

If you want to import your two JS files, just do this :

```
<!-- Include external JS code -->
<script src="/javascripts/validation.js"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/other.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!-- local JS code -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="my-template">/* some local JS code */</script> 
<script type="text/x-template" id="myfile-template">/* some local JS code */</script>
```

Comment: Did you notice the [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/) template?

Comment: We can include a <script> tag inside other <script> tag in backbone js.Here I am able to call one js file easily but in case of including of multiple js, its not working.